# Как объединить два объекта javascript c объединением значений ключей

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть несколько объектов:

`{ 'key1': 1, 'key2': 4 , 'key3': 2}
{ 'key6': 2, 'key2': 4 , 'key7': 9}`

Нужно их объединить так, чтобы получилось:
`{ 'key1': 1, 'key7': 9, 'key6': 2, 'key2': 8 , 'key3': 2}`

То есть, чтобы значения дублирующихся ключей приплюсовались друг к другу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так

```js
let o1 = { 'key1': 1, 'key2': 4 , 'key3': 2};
let o2 = { 'key6': 2, 'key2': 4 , 'key7': 9};

Object.keys(o2).map(k => o1[k] = o2[k] + (o1[k] || 0));

console.log(o1)
```

Вот вариант для 3 объектов

```js
let o1 = { 'key1': 1, 'key2': 4 , 'key3': 2};
let o2 = { 'key6': 2, 'key2': 4 , 'key7': 9};
let o3 = { 'key6': 1, 'key2': 1 , 'key7': 1};

[o2,o3].reduce((a, o) => {
    Object.keys(o).map(k => a[k] = (a[k] || 0) + o[k])
    return a;
}, o1)


console.log(o1)
```

Comment: а delete  зачем?

Comment: А если объектов больше 2-х?

Comment: Спасибо этот вариант идеально подходит

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Там у вас обновленном варианте ошибка, вместо o[k] o[key]

Comment: @Ryner спасибо, починил

Comment: не o1,  а `a` надо возвращать, и  map на reduce поменять

Comment: @Grundy, верно подмечено, причем если посмотреть ответы до правки, там было корректно, это я потом нареfuckторил